# Squid3 athentication whit MS server Active Direcory

Tags: active-directory, debian, authentication, squid, kerberos

Is there an easy way for Squid to use MS AD database?

Comment: This is a "professional networking" Q&A site. No need for commentary such as yours. I edited your question accordingly.

Comment: Please show me where it says professional or where there are only professional Q&A, some how that doesn't appear anywhere

Comment: The site is specifically a question and answer site for "managing information technology systems in a business environment" (per the [tour](http://serverfault.com/tour)). I'd figure you would equate *business environment* with *professional*. Perhaps I didn't need to point that out though: There's no place for that language here, period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still use NTLM or basic auth with PAM. So, yes.

Plus, your question describes almost nothing about what you have done and what failed.
By the way, I have an old article written about squid authentication methods and AD integration, not covering Kerberos (well, actually it does, but I think that saying *Kerberos* you are referring to GSS-SPNEGO auth), so looks like it's the one you need. Kind of compilation from various sources, coupled with my experience. Not a source of copy-paste, but rather a good theoretical example, you could check [it](http://squidquotas.hq.norma.perm.ru/squid-auth.shtml) out.

Comment: Thanks, the NTLM was what i was looking for, but the PAM is whit kerberos